# How i will get current page title in hidden field, when i submit the form in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, eloquent, gmail

I have a form which have name, email and phone. But i want current page title or url when user submit the form, Because I want to track the user page. Please let me know How i can do it.
This is my form code.

```
<form class="callus" method="post" action="{{url('/sendmailuser')}}">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="single-query form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_title" value="{{ request('request') }}" class="keyword-input" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="single-query form-group">
            <input type="text" name="user_name" class="keyword-input" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="single-query form-group">
            <input type="text" name="user_email" class="keyword-input" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="single-query form-group">
            <input type="text" name="user_phone" class="keyword-input" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required="Field is required">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="single-query form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="submit now" class="btn-blue">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my Email send code...

```
public function sendyourmail(Request $r)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($r->all(), [
        'user_name' => 'required',
        'user_email' =>'required',
        'user_phone' =>'required',
        'user_desc' =>'required', 
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $data=[
        'user_email' => $r->user_email,
        'user_name' => $r->user_name,
        'user_phone' => $r->user_phone,
        'user_desc' => $r->user_desc,
    ];
    Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) use($data) {
        $message->from($data['user_email'], 'Email Form Sumit');
        $message->to('sumit@gmail.com')->cc('sumit@sumit.com');
        $message->subject($data['user_desc']);
    });
    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Your Mail Has Been sent Successfully, We Will Get Back to You Shortly.');
}
```

Comment: Hidden input fields work like any other field. You can simply access it through `product_title`

Comment: This is my view page, But still unable to get title in mail

<section id="contact-us">
 <div class="contact">
  <b>Product Name:</b>{{$product_title}}<br>
  <b>User Name:</b>{{$user_name}}<br>
  <b>User Mail:</b>{{$user_email}}<br>
  <b>User Contact:</b>{{$user_phone}}<br>
  <b>User Message:</b> {!! $user_desc !!}<br>
 </div>
</section>

Answer (score 0):

You should define the title of the rendered page within the controller and past it as parameter to the view when you specify which template should be rendered.

```
public function sendyourmailform()
{
    $title = 'Sample Page Title';
    return view('email_template.blade.php', compact('title'));
}
```

Because the title variable is past to the template you can access it inside the template by rendering it twice inside the title `section`

```
@section('title')
    {{ $title }}
@endsection
```

Inside the layout page which is extends by the template which render the form you should have define section named `title` like this

```
<head>
    <title>
        @section('title')
        @endsection
    <title>
</head>
```

And you have access to the title variable inside the template part which show the related form.

```
<form class="callus" method="post" action="{{url('/sendmailuser')}}">
    @csrf
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="page_title" value="{{ $title }}">
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: product_title (View: /home/amit/Desktop/project/resources/views/product-single.blade.php)